# GAE: 30-40 Second Queries to Cloud SQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, google-app-engine

I am running a Google App Engine Java web application with Spring, Hibernate and MySQL (Cloud SQL). Locally all my queries take about 500ms each but once I deploy my app some queries can take as long as 40 seconds.  When I turn on MySQL statistics (via org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG) no single query is taking an abnormally large amount of time but each time a query is executed, it has to acquire a JDBC connection which takes half a second. "569422089 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;"  That's way too long.  Is there something I can look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into adding a connection pool as hinted in the [Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#connections).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I thought you might be on to something here!  I added dbcp and indeed, some queries that were previously taking 1.5s - 2s went down to 700ms, so big win but some of my other queries are preforming so poorly.  Any other ideas?